# SSRS report page break issue

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I have a problem with page breaks in an SSRS report, and I'm by no means an expert. This is in the XML mark up to provide a page break:

```
<TableGroups>
  <TableGroup>
    <Grouping Name="AdjustmentPageBreakGroup">
      <PageBreakAtEnd>true</PageBreakAtEnd>
      <GroupExpressions>
        <GroupExpression>=CInt(Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/28))</GroupExpression>
      </GroupExpressions>
    </Grouping>
  </TableGroup>
</TableGroups>
```

The page break appears on different lines on the print and screen version of the report:

**Print:**

[image]

**Screen:**

[image]

As you can see, the print version has a break in the middle of the "Transfer IN" cell, with "Value" on the next page after the break. From what I can tell from the XML, it's got a hardcoded page break at row 28, and if I change this number it fixes the print version and breaks the screen version. Is there any way to specify this line break differently for print and screen?

Comment: Would it be possible that the page break occurs because the maximum page length has been reached?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue is the rectangle component. Based on your image, I am assuming that your report has a table that is grouped on location. For each location you are reporting on Number and Value. Column 1 has the location name, Column 2 is the label and Column 3 is the field values.

Create a new table (TABLE A). Set the table to group on Location. In the group footer, add a rectangle (RECTANGLE). Set the Keep Contents Together property of the rectangle to TRUE.

Add a table to the area of the rectangle (TABLE B). Do not add a grouping to TABLE B. Add to the details row of this table Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3 formatted as it is in the existing report.

When the report renders, each group will be kept together and the rectangle will force page breaks between the groupings.

The solution above works for SSRS 2008.  The solution below is similar and works for SSRS 2005.

Create a new table (TABLE A). Set the table to group on Location. In the group header or footer add a table (TABLE B). Do not add a grouping to TABLE B. Add to the details row of this table Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3 formatted as it is in the existing report.  On the TABLE B use the Fir table on one page if possible option.

Comment: I cannot find a "Keep contents together" property on the rectangle? I'm using SSRS 2005.

Comment: I dont think this answer is correct. There's a Keep together property on a table, but not a rectangle, but you cannot nest tables so this won't work.

Comment: I've edited the answer after playing with this in SSRS 2005 a bit.  There are a few feature changes between the two.  Be sure the second table is added to the header or footer.  The detail area won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using few small steps:

1-Go to report properties and set paper size to custom. The width and length is to be as such, that it will show all column :
[image]

2- Then set the Body Property like same :
[image]

Now View the report and download in any PDF/Any format it will not break:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the interactive size and the page size are the same. You also have to set the margins so that the print version prints properly.